# AUCTeX automatic extraction: beyond regexps

Tags: auctex

In my custom style support file, I would like to add custom code to parse an environment. That is, my LaTeX code looks like this

```
\begin{foobar}
  some complex stuff
\end{foobar}
```

and I don't want to capture `some complex stuff` in a regexp, it's too complex for that, but I do want to analyze it. I can't use generic entries to parse `some complex stuff` because they would have a ridiculous amount of false positives outside the `foobar` environment. I can capture the beginning of the environment in an entry in [`TeX-auto-regexp-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Hacking-the-Parser.html#Hacking-the-Parser), but what am I supposed to put in my function?

```
(defun TeX-parse-foobar-environment (match)
  (let ((name (TeX-match-buffer match))
        (start ???) (end ???))
    (parse-foobar-region start end)))
(TeX-auto-add-regexp '("\\\\begin{\\(foobar\\)}" 1 TeX-parse-foobar-environment))
```

I don't see anything about this in the manual. Should I call `LaTeX-find-matching-begin` then `LaTeX-find-matching-end` to determine where the environment starts and ends? How does this generalize to examples other than environments? I could find out empirically where the point is, but can I count on that being the same in all versions of AUCTeX?

Answer (score 1):

AUCTeX parser works with regexps, and the position of the matches isn't recorded.  I think you have 2 choices:

- Leave the parser alone and write a function which does the job.  Maybe something like this:

  ````el
  (defun gilles/TeX-parse-foobar-environment ()
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let (beg end result)
        (while (re-search-forward "^[ \t]*\\\\begin{foobar}" nil t)
          (setq beg (line-beginning-position 2))
          (LaTeX-find-matching-end)
          (setq end (line-end-position 0))
          (push (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end) result))
        (dolist (x (nreverse result))
          (parse-foobar-region x)))))   ```
  ````
- Or really plug into AUCTeX parser and do something like this in your custom style file:

  ```el
  (TeX-auto-add-type "gilles-env-foobar" "LaTeX")

  (defvar LaTeX-gilles-foobar-regexp
    '("\\\\begin{foobar}\\(.*?\\(?:\n.*?\\)*?\\)\\\\end{foobar}"
      1 LaTeX-auto-gilles-env-foobar))

  (defun LaTeX-gilles-foobar-auto-prepare ()
    (setq LaTeX-auto-gilles-env-foobar nil))

  (add-hook 'TeX-auto-prepare-hook
            #'LaTeX-gilles-foobar-auto-prepare t)

  (TeX-add-style-hook
   "gilles-style"
   (lambda ()
     (TeX-auto-add-regexp LaTeX-gilles-foobar-regexp))
   :latex)

  (defun gilles/TeX-parse-foobar-environment ()
    (dolist (x (LaTeX-gilles-env-foobar-list))
      (gilles-parser-fun-taking-one-string-as-arg x)))
  ```

  `TeX-auto-add-type` is a macro which defined some variables and a functionen needed for parsing.  `LaTeX-gilles-foobar-regexp` tells AUCTeX what to parse and where to put the match.  The middle part adds all of this to parser.  The final part is to write `gilles-parser-fun-taking-one-string-as-arg` which takes a string as argument which is the content of the environment, say `some complex stuff` you want to parse.

All this is of course 100% untested.